# Html + Css good response on computer (even in minimized mode) but bad on mobile

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I used a ready-made template for my project.

I don't know much about html and Css, I just deleted and customized some of the code by trial and error.

To test mobile response, I minimized my web browser on the PC. Everything was fine...  Now I encountered this when I tested it on my phone.

This is the mobile browser - very bad
[image]

How is this possible? Everything is bad - see footer! It shows footer like PC not mobile - why?
The best and fastest way to solve this problem in the whole project?

Comment: "I don't know much about html and Css" ... Take a tutorial. Plenty of them online.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Do you know how to use your browser devtools inspect facility? Also do you have a meta tag in your head element that sets info about the viewport? Something like <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

Comment: @GetSet maybe i need that but not have enough time now... now i just need know about Tags that determine the response between mobile and computer

Comment: @0stone0 sry i added some code

Comment: Not knowing what you are doing is not saving time. It actually wastes more time.

Comment: @AHaworth i know something about** inspect in firefox**.
no i removed everything that I thought were extra... in `head` i just have this :` 3 of "stylesheet"`

Comment: What is 3 of stylesheet? Also make sure you have a meta element like the above. If you use your browser inspect and select a phone what do you see?

Comment: @AHaworth Thank yoooooou bro... This was the problem with all pages and responses ... just i added this    ` <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` And the problem is solved

Comment: "I spent 20 days on this" ... wow bro.

Comment: @AHaworth Please post the answer... There may be many people like me who use the ready-made template and think "<meta>" is extra...  I didn't know how important it was! ... i thought should check all Css... thank you bro realy thank you

Comment: @GetSet man i dont know about html/css - infact i dont like front-end... I am a backend developer ... I don't even know the basics about "html/css". I always have either front-end work... or I use ready-made templates...

Comment: I prefer ready-made templates myself.

Comment: @GetSet Everything depends on my employer... sometimes he is poor... so I have to use a ready-made template... but it was a good experience, I didn't think <meta> was so important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit reluctant to post this as an answer as it is fairly basic, but I do appreciate that there may be people who don't recognise its importance.

Make sure this line is in your head element.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag for more detail.

And a warning - if you use other people's code remove stuff only if you  understand it - and look up things you are not sure about on MDN for example.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the head element of your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```